# How best to include an angularjs page on demand?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on my first AngularJS app it I want it to be as efficient as possible. I have forms I want to use stand-alone and also to reuse within other pages. I'm trying to learn the best way to do this.

For example, consider this snippet from my home page:

```
Welcome, {{name}}. Click here to update your address data.
```

At this point, I have only loaded the data for the person's identity. I don't want to request the address data unless the user clicks the here link. Then (and only then), I want to retrieve the address record and load an address form for the user to update.

The form I want 'stands alone' in another angular 'page,' e.g., myApp/address/person_id, but I don't want to redirect the user to that page. I just want to 'include' its form.

Can anyone suggest best practice(s) for this?

Comment: Turn the form into a directive or component. Then wherever you need it you just insert `<my-form></my-form>`

Comment: My address form is a component, so I need to learn two more things:
1) How to insert the component only after the user clicks?
2) How to 'send' the id to the component dynamically, e.g., <address person-id="43"></address>?

Comment: A simple `ng-if` should cover that issue

Comment: Once you have done an XHR for a persons name, it adds delay to do another XHR for additional information. Think in terms of minimizing the number of XHRs not the contents of each XHR. Use the `ng-view` directive and a router such as [ng-route](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs-ng-route/info) or [UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-ui-router/info) to load view templates on demand.